# How can I modify the browser control for phonegap in iOS to have menu buttons?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a PhoneGap application in iOS to display a web app. I want to modify the browser control that is displaying the web app to have a few buttons at the bottom that function as "back" "forward" "refresh" etc. is this possible? Do I need to use a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using html to implement those buttons, which is pretty easy with javascript. Since it's not performance-critical, doing this with native code is unnecessary.

I don't know any plugins for what exactly you want, but I have used the android version of this [iOS ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser) which provides a pop-up browser with "back", "forward" and "refresh" buttons. It's quite convenient for browsing external web pages.

Comment: The childbrowser plugin worked perfectly! I just had to modify it to remove some things I didn't need. Thanks.